# PySimpleGUI и переменная ввода

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Всем привет.
Я только начал изучать питон, буду благодарен, если подскажете.
Мне нужна программа, которая может проверять никнеймы на двух сайтах. Есть графический интерфейс.
Суть проблемы, в том, что после нажатия кнопки открываются сразу две ссылки даже если ничего не введено.
Я хочу сделать, чтобы программа проверяла, введено ли что-то и где именно и относительно этого открывала ссылки.
Первое, что не понятно, это сделать, чтобы то, что введено в окно 1 отделить от того, что введено в окно 2.
Хочу сделать 2 переменные и проверять их

```
import webbrowser
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('Black')
layout = [ [sg.Text('Проверка на форуме'), sg.InputText()],
         [sg.Text('Проверка на StatName'), sg.InputText()],
         [sg.Button('Проверить')] ]
window = sg.Window('ForumCheck', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    fr=(values[0])
    webbrowser.open(f"https://www.gipsyteam.ru/profile/{fr}")
    webbrowser.open(f"https://statname.net/player_search?term={fr}")
```

Comment: Оффтоп. Функция `webbrowser.open` просто откроет ссылки в браузере по умолчанию. Как-то попарсить это можно будет зрительно - глазами посмотреть (или подключить машинное зрение, например, через opencv :D). Если вы хотите это в коде, то можно сделать через `requests` (чтобы загрузить по ссылке) и вероятно `bs4` (чтобы парсить html) или через selenium, если сайт сильно завязан на javascript. Если что-то непонятно - гуглите :)

Comment: Так мне и нужно просто открыть ссылки и подоставить значения из переменных. Как сделать переменные уже нашёл, теперь не могу сделать проверку введена ли строка или нет, что бы открывать только ту ссылку, где введена строка

Answer (score 1):

Добавил:

- Ключи к полям и кнопке
- Логику при клике на кнопку с извлечением значений полей

Если нужна проверка введенного значения в полях используйте `if <переменная>:`:, пример:

```
if gipsyteam:
    webbrowser.open(f"https://www.gipsyteam.ru/profile/{gipsyteam}")
```

Пример:

```
import webbrowser
import PySimpleGUI as sg


sg.theme('Black')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Проверка на форуме'), sg.InputText(key='input_gipsyteam')],
    [sg.Text('Проверка на StatName'), sg.InputText(key='input_statname')],
    [sg.Button('Проверить', key='button_check')]
]
window = sg.Window('ForumCheck', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break

    if event == 'button_check':
        gipsyteam = values['input_gipsyteam']
        statname = values['input_statname']

        webbrowser.open(f"https://www.gipsyteam.ru/profile/{gipsyteam}")
        webbrowser.open(f"https://statname.net/player_search?term={statname}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import webbrowser
import PySimpleGUI
from PySimpleGUI import theme, Window, Text, InputText, Button


class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        theme('green')
        layout = [[Text('Проверка на форуме'), InputText()],
                  [Text('Проверка на StatName'), InputText()],
                  [Button('Проверить')]]
        self.window = Window('ForumCheck', layout)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            event, values = self.window.read()
            # print(f"Event: {event}\nValues: {values}") # Смотрим что из себя представляют event и values
            if event == PySimpleGUI.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
                break
        
            # Если нажата кнопка с текстом 'Проверить' то провалиться в блок
            elif event == "Проверить":
                # Будем проверять с учётом того что в один момент будет заполненно только одно поле ввода
                if values[0]:
                    webbrowser.open(f"https://www.gipsyteam.ru/profile/{values[0]}")
                elif values[1]:
                    webbrowser.open(f"https://statname.net/player_search?term={values[1]}")


def main():
    Application().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```